# How to get sheetname of the uploaded excel file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, file-upload, oledb

I would like to get the sheet name of the uploaded excel file using `C#` code. The file may be in `.xls` or `.xlsx` format. The Code I have used is as follows:

```
protected void btnGenerateCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string sourceFile = ExcelFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
    string worksheetName = ?? //(How to get the first sheetname of the uploaded file)                
    string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

    if (sourceFile.Contains(".xlsx"))
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";

    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);

        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                string rowString = "";
                for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
                {
                    rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\",";
                }
                wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
            }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
        wrtr.Close();
        wrtr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

- (How to get the first `sheetname` of the uploaded file)
  `string worksheetName = ??`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this to get sheet names from a `.xlsx` file and loop through all the names to read sheets one by one.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
connection.Open();
DataTable Sheets = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

foreach(DataRow dr in Sheets.Rows)
{
    string sht = dr[2].ToString().Replace("'", "");
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sht + "]", connection);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am just getting an empty string. Please help out.

Comment: @prabuR is the datatable sheets empty? can you show the code that you tried

Comment: conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();

                DataTable Sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                foreach (DataRow dr in Sheets.Rows)
                {
                    worksheetName = dr[0].ToString();
                }
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]", conn);

Comment: Excel file I have uploaded is having 1 sheet

Comment: is DataTable Sheets empty?

Comment: use worksheetName = dr[2].ToString(); here 2 specifies the position of column

Comment: It works. Thanks. Is there any way to give the sheetname of the generated file similar to the uploaded file's sheetname?

Comment: how do you generate the file ? using interop?

Comment: No. I have updated the question with the complete code I have used.

Comment: i dont think you can..seems you are appending string ..try if its possible through an interop

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable Sheets = oleConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

for(int i=0;i<Sheets.Rows.Count;i++)
{
   string worksheets= Sheets.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
   string sqlQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", worksheets);
}
```

Comment: Please add some commentary as to what is going on here.

Comment: the code fetches excel schema into datatable and iterates over to find the sheetnames. karthik as used integer index to access sheet name and i have used the column name["TABLE_NAME"] which is more precise

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel is too big, This code will waste a lot of time in(conn.open()). Use Openxml will be better(use less time),but if the Excel is Open---Using openxml to read will have the exception but oldbhelper wile have no exception. My english is pool , sorry.-----Chinese boy

Comment: Could you provide the code on how to do it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft excel library Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Then you can use index to get the worksheet name as following.

```
        string path = @"C\Desktop\MyExcel.xlsx" //Path for excel
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
        xlAPP = new Excel.Application();
        xlAPP.Visible = false;
        xlWbk = xlAPP.Workbooks.Open(path);
        string worksheetName = xlWbk.Worksheets.get_Item(1).Name //pass Index here. Reemember that index starts from 1.
        xlAPP.Quit();
        releaseObject(xlWbk);
        releaseObject(xlAPP);

    //Always handle unmanaged code.
    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```